# Display array contents in mail - phpmailer

Tags: php, arrays, phpmailer

So i have

mail.php -> sends mail

index.php -> mail body structure

I want to send array values from mail.php to index.php and iterate the array contents in html.

mail.php

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 
require '../inc/database.php';

$query = "  query " ;

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $arr[]=$row;
        print_r($arr);
    }
} 
// $arr returns Array ( [0] => Array ( [val1] => 1 [val2] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [val1] => a [val2] => b) 

....
mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents("index.php")); // Body of my mail 
...
?>
```

index.php

```
...
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tr>
   <td style="padding: 15px 0 0 0; color: #153643; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;">
      // Display my array contents here 
   </td>
  </tr>                                                            
</table>
...
```

i want my output to look like:

1:2

a:b

How can this be achieved ? How can i pass array variables from mail.php page to index.php page and loop the array value there?